# ngrok not connecting to local server

Tags: ngrok

So, I am running ngrok (current version) on my Mac OSx. But I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to complete tunnel connection
The connection to http://35504712.ngrok.io was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client, but the client failed to establish a connection to the local address localhost:3746.

Make sure that a web service is running on localhost:3746 and that it is a valid address.

The error encountered was: dial tcp xx.xx.xx.xx:3746: getsockopt: connection refused
```

I know my server is running properly, as I can actually click the link to my localserver in the error message and get a response from my server.

Any ideas on how to diagnose?

Answer (score -2):

Have you made sure you're running ngrok inside your project directory, also can you still access localhost:3746?

Also what command are you using to start hosting the ngrok sever?

Comment: Not sure it matters if I run ngrok in my project folder. I did just to see, and no change. The command I am using is "ngrok http 3746"